# pupteer navigation by changing url params (without clicking)

Tags: puppeteer

I want to navigate into page by changing its endpoints params , is that possible?

```
const pupteer = async ()=>{
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({...options})
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto("http://example.com/123");
      await doSomthing(page)
      await page.goto("http://example.com/456")
      await doSomthing(page)
      await browser.close();
 
}
```

I know how to navigate by clicking but there are other issues that make me wonder if it is possible by changing url endpoints.

The code above does not work when I change the url, I'm pretty sure I'm missing somthing...

Answer (score 0):

Your url is missing double qoute, it should be

```
  await page.goto("http://example.com/123");
```

Comment: ok, I fixed it for a better preview but it is not the main issue of that question...

Comment: There's no issue with your preview, can you reproduce your issue with more detail? For example, what  `await doSomthing(page)` is doing?

Comment: nothing special , just taking some data from some selectors (that are same in each endpoint) , so generally i want repat doSomthing(page) on 10 different urls

Comment: That function would cause the problem, you should demonstrate it so everyone can figure out what's going on with your code.

Comment: ok, so according to your comments , there is no issue with navigation by changing url in page.goto(url)? (anyway i paste the doSomthing as an edit in my question